# How to use PEX with NUnit tests in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, nunit, pex

I am aware that the current release of PEX allows use with the NUnit framework.

The thing is I can't configure it to use the NUnit framework.

In the Options -> PEX: What Exactly do i have to put in the "TestFramework" and "TestFrameworkDirectory".

I Have tried many combinations but failed to achieve any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've went to the DevLabs forum in search for a solution, I've got a solution to the problem.

Here it is:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/pex/thread/5f7cc37d-0b8e-4bad-af6f-c53c5076e7c2

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the "TestFramework" option to "NUnit" (without quotes) and the "TestFrameworkDirectory" option to the directory where the nunit.framework.dll file is located (if you used the .msi installer it's probably "%ProgramFiles%\NUnit x.y.z\bin\net-2.0\framework").